# Why iron is not discussed more as a probable cause of "Bronze age collapse"?

Tags: bronze-age, iron-age, collapse

Most discussed possible causes for Bronze Age Collapse are

- Climate change

  - Droughts (either natural, or caused by deforestation)
  - Volcanic eruption
- Sea People

But Bonze Age Collapse is also begining of Iron age. It seem rather obvious question to ask if the main cause was the iron itself?

At high-shool I heave heard that Dorians who invaded Mycenean Greece and Crete were equipped by iron weapons. But I never saw this discussed more broadly in context of Bronze Age Collapse in general (Egypt, Hittite, Assyria ...).

Were military and socio-economic changes caused by spread of iron technology (similarly as European colonialism and industrial revolution, end of feudalism are strongly connected to technological disruption and caused collapse of large empires - Ottoman, Mugdal India, Qing China ... )

I don't speak so much about iron weapons being superior to bronze weapons, or about invaders (sea people) heaving particularly good iron weapons.

What I find more reasonable, is to consider that centralized power-structure of these societies was build around control of these rare resources (bronze,copper,tin). When iron started to spread, they loose "monopoly on power" and failed to adjust.

**EDIT:**

The conection of Broze age collapse with ironworking is discussed to some degree 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_Bronze_Age_collapse#Ironworking

Nevertheless, considering how obvious this question is for an outsider (i.e. not profesional archeologist or historian) I would assume, historians would spend more time explaining why this is not the primary hypothesis.

Comment: How is your question not answered by the Wikipedia article on {Late bronze Age Collapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_Bronze_Age_collapse#Ironworking)?

Comment: The transitions between the raw materials for tool making are not hard ones. They are gradual, differ geographically, some materials never get into broader use in places (e.g. bronze in Egypt). I mean, the question is cool with many facets, but books have already been written. It's complex, i'd stay with the current working hypotheses ...

Comment: The transition from the Late Bronze Age to the Iron Age _is_ generally suggested as one of the factors in the collapse.  However, few of the societies that were hit hardest actually controlled access to copper,or (more especially) tin.  In fact, the Wikipedia page on the Late Bronze Age collapse includes a section on the [possible causes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_Bronze_Age_collapse#Possible_causes), and the transition to the Iron Age is indeed listed there.

Comment: One should also mention that the "bronze age collapse" (I hate the term) is a regional, mostly Aegan/Near East thing.

Comment: I am surprised with closing votes for this interesting question. No reference is given in the comments, except Wikipedia article which does not really address the question. As I understand the question it is not about "transition of technologies" but a question about possible military use of the new technology. Where is this possible reason addressed?

Comment: @Alex The Wikipedia article addresses that under "Changes in warfare" (although the question explicitly states it isn't about whether iron weapons were superior)..  However, the title actually asks why Iron isn't cited more as a cause.  As the Wikipedia article shows, the transition from the Late Bronze Age to the Iron Age **is** generally cited as a possible cause for the collapse.  Finally, the last paragraph contains an assertion without any supporting evidence. As I noted above, few of the societies that were hardest hit actually controlled access to copper,or (more especially) tin.

Comment: OK, it is cited, but just on so much. It is not dominent hypothesis. I would expect since it is so obvious question, you have to first disprove before you start to theoretize about other reasons.

Comment: I went for "Left Open" because entire narrative histories of this period (namely Cline's "1171 BC") did not mention technological change as happening at all in this period. The recommended Wikipedia link -- while it should have been included by the OP -- is also vague and unhelpful.

Comment: @ProkopHapala: Archeologists don't waste time explaining why something is not the case (negative assertions a logical difficulty), but why something else may be the case, and the evidence connected to that. Also, the bronze age world is much bigger and diverse than the Aegean/Near-East at the fringe of history and pre-history.

Comment: Questions of the form "Why doesn't X get more attention" are invariably opinion-based, and often push questions.

Comment: I think I share your observation that the change over to iron age warfare methods seems glaringly obvious as a causative agent for all the chaos. However, I wouldn't know how to answer this particular question about why others think a certain thing, and it seems very much like a "push question" rather than an actual question. Perhaps the question could be rephrased to ask what's the case *against* that being the primary cause?